# What is the name for this special case of the Travelling Salesman involving dynamic edge costs?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, traveling-salesman

This is a modeling / taxonomy question.  Is there a name for this type of problem?

I came up with the following graph problem for a pizza delivery truck, which starts with zero dollars and enough fuel to drive N miles.  They want to deliver pizza to C customers.  Each customer will immediately pay them some number of dollars.

Edge weights in this graph are the number of miles between destinations.

Vertices in the graph aren't just customers.  They also include "gas station" nodes -- places at which the delivery truck can refuel, converting money on hand to "miles able to drive".

The problem is, given a starting location, how much money on hand and/or gas in the tank does the truck need to delivery pizza to every customer, and still return home?

This isn't the classic Travelling Salesman problem because there are two types of resources in play here, $ and fuel.  And there's a resource constraint -- the problem isn't just about finding the minimum cost.  It's about finding the minimum starting resources necessary to be able to complete a circuit.

Comment: @Barranka I would rather say http://cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well,algorithms are also kinda related topic to Stack Overflow @Barranka,though,I agree with you minutely!

Comment: @addy2012 WOW! Another SE site new to me! Worth taking a peek!

Comment: @shekharsuman Indeed, algorithms are an SO topic... but I think this particular (and quite interesting) question deserves a more rigorous mathematical treatment before actualy writing the algorithm. It deserves every up-vote it can get, but I still think it should be migrated to a site where there might be better answers.

Comment: Appreciate the enthusiasm.  Note I'm just curious if this problem has a general name;  has been defined and solved anywhere before.

Comment: This question is probably better suited to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com than SO; the folks there are more likely to have an answer.

Comment: Just a note - [cstheory.se] is for **research-level** questions; [cs.se] is for your run-of-the-mill questions, such as this (I'd say)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a name for this, but there's a straightforward NP-hardness reduction from TSP:  Given a TSP instance and length L, create a Pizza instance with the same graph, L starting fuel and no gas stations.